# Calculation on each value inside a vector, and aggregate the results to a vector

Tags: r

I have a problem which I need to do some manipulations on a vector, for each value inside the vector, I need to calculate the 'ramping-up' values for this value given the ramping-up range `L`.

For example, a value `10` at the `3rd` position, the ramping-up function will return `[2.5, 5]`, which should be the ramping-up values for this value `10` , and they are at the `1st, 2nd` positions.

The results I want to have is a singe vector which is also a vector, but with all the ramping-up effects.

I have used some ways to successfully get the correct results.

Because I need to do a lot of such operation, so I am wondering if there is a faster way to achieve it. (profvis shows this operation is the bottleneck of my script)

Here is a simple example

```r
x = c(0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 20, 10)
L = 2

r = matrix(0, L, length(x))
for(i in 1: L)
{
       r[i, ] = map(x, ramp, L) %>% 
                map_dbl(i) %>% 
                lead(L-i+1, default = 0)
}
```

```r
r
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]     [,6] [,7]
[1,] 1.250000 2.500000 2.500000 5.000000  2.500000 0.000000    0
[2,] 0.000000 2.500000 5.000000 5.000000 10.000000 5.000000    0
```

The first row of the resulting matrix `r` is the the first ramping-up values after shift to the right position, the second row is the second ramping-up values.

The final return vector I want to have is

```r
colSums(r)
```

Any suggestion is welcome, appreciate it.

for clarity, here is the `ramp()` function I used, the half ramping is just an example for easy understanding.

```r
ramp <- function(Value, Len, R = 0.5)
{
  out <- c(1:(Len+1)) 
  if(R != 0) { out <- exp(R*c(1:(Len+1)))*Value/exp(R*(Len+1)) } 
  else { out <- c(rep(0, Len), Value) } 
  return(out)
}

x = c(0, 0, 5, 10, 10, 20, 10)
L = 2

r = matrix(0, L, length(x))
for(i in 1: L)
{
   r[i, ] = map(x, ramp, L) %>% map_dbl(i) %>% lead(L-i+1, default = 0)
}
r
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]     [,6] [,7]
[1,] 1.839397 3.678794 3.678794 7.357589  3.678794 0.000000    0
[2,] 0.000000 3.032653 6.065307 6.065307 12.130613 6.065307    0
```

This is the result

```r
colSums(r)
[1]  1.839397  6.711448  9.744101 13.422895 15.809408  6.065307  0.000000
```

Comment: What is `ramp`?  It is not defined in the code

Comment: Hello, akrun, `ramp()` is just a function, it is used to calculate the ramping-up values for given value `x` and ramp length `L`. In my example, `ramp(10, 2)` will return `[2.5, 5, 10]`.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have that function, but base don your expected result, somebody needs to come up withit, right ? Ok, got it

Comment: Vectorizing or speeding up `ramp()` is probably the best way to speed up your code. What does `profvis` show for time spent in `ramp()` vs time spent in other stuff. If `ramp` is vectorized already, then speed-up is easy. If ramp isn't vectorizable, again, speed-up is easy. If ramp can't be vectorized, then there's probably not a lot to be done. So please, share `ramp`.

Comment: And also, it's near impossible for us to actually try anything out without `ramp`.

Comment: @Gregor, @akrun, I edited my question, and provided the `ramp` function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post my several attempts so far to improve the efficiency of the process.

The first thing I did is to optimize my `ramp.all()` steps, which are the second part of my script in my example.

```r
ramp.all.old.1 <- function(x, L)
{
  r = rep(0, length(x))
  for(i in 1: L)
  {
    r = rbind(r, map(x, ramp, L) %>% map_dbl(i) %>% lead(L-i+1, default = 0))
  }
  return(colSums(r))
}
```

As I read other articles, I noticed that `rbind()` may not be the best choice for my purpose. So the first attempt is to pre-allocate the result matrix `r` , so I got the second version.

```r
ramp.all.old.2 <- function(x, L)
{
   r = matrix(0, L, length(x))
   for(i in 1: L)
   {
       r[i, ] = map(x, ramp, L) %>% map_dbl(i) %>% lead(L-i+1, default = 0)
   }
   return(colSums(r))
}
```

Then, when I took a close look of my code inside the loop, I noticed that `map()` there is actually redundant, it only needs to calculate once before the loop. So I moved map() out, and substitute it with `lapply()`.

```r
ramp.all.old.3 <- function(x, L)
{
  r = matrix(0, L, length(x))
  tmp = lapply(x, ramp, L)
  for(i in 1: L)
  {
      r[i, ] = tmp %>% map_dbl(i) %>% lead(L-i+1, default = 0)
  }
  return(colSums(r))
}
```

Similarly, it looks like the `map_dbl()` is not optimized, there are a better ways. So, I came out with version 4.

```r
ramp.all.old.4 <- function(x, L)
{
  r = matrix(0, L, length(x))
  tmp = as.data.frame(data.table::transpose(lapply(x, ramp, L)), col.names = letters[1:(L+1)])
  for(i in 1: L)
  {
    r[i, ] = lead(tmp[, i], L-i+1, default = 0)
  }
  return(colSums(r))
}
```

As @Gregor suggested, speeding up the `ramp()` function is very important also here. I figured a way to change my `ramp()` function which is now can take **vector** as a input, by utilizing the **out-product** operation. I came up with `ramp.new()` function

```r
ramp.new <- function(Value, Len, R = 0.5)
{
   out = Value %*% t(exp(R*c(1:(Len+1)))/exp(R*(Len+1))) 
   return(out)
}
```

The new `ramp.all()` function is

```r
ramp.all <- function(x, L)
{
   r = matrix(0, L, length(x))
   tmp = ramp.new(x, L)
   for(i in 1: L)
   {
     r[i, ] = lead(tmp[, i], L-i+1, default = 0)
   }
   return(colSums(r))
}
```

Here is the performance testing results.

```r
x
[1]  0  0  5 10 10 20 10
```

```r
microbenchmark(ramp.all.old.1(x, 2)->res.1, ramp.all.old.2(x, 2)->res.2, ramp.all.old.3(x, 2)->res.3, ramp.all.old.4(x, 2)->res.4,ramp.all(x, 2)->res.5)
Unit: microseconds
                          expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval  cld
 res.1 <- ramp.all.old.1(x, 2) 529.461 565.0145 603.9836 589.810 618.7990  816.800   100    d
 res.2 <- ramp.all.old.2(x, 2) 526.909 565.1965 619.6961 590.357 623.7215 1684.649   100    d
 res.3 <- ramp.all.old.3(x, 2) 441.582 472.0305 512.1629 500.655 525.0860  859.463   100   c 
 res.4 <- ramp.all.old.4(x, 2) 299.736 331.4610 375.3600 350.422 385.7930 1232.857   100  b  
       res.5 <- ramp.all(x, 2)  34.277  47.7680  56.4947  50.504  56.3385  137.470   100 a
```

```
identical(res.1, res.2, res.3, res.4, res.5)
[1] TRUE
```

I am pretty happy so far. Checking the `profvis`, it seems I should focus on `lead()` function in next step.

Any other suggestions are welcome, and thank you all @akrun, @Gregor.